# Printing Array of Objects from API call in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Trying to deconstruct my API call from Triposo API within my React.js application. The controller is set up:

```js
axios.get(url)
     .then(results => 
              ({
                  walkTime: results.data.results[0].walk_duration,
                  distance: results.data.results[0].walk_distance,
                  stops: results.data.results[0].way_points[0]
              })
          )
     .then(
         walks => res.json(walks))
                     .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err))
```

I have a component, shown below, which passes the props to my WalkCard.

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        {this.state.walk ? (
          <WalkCard
          walkTime={this.state.walk.time}
          distance={this.state.walk.distance}
          stops={this.state.walk.stops}
          />
        ) : <h3>No Results to Display</h3>}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

`console.log("props" + JSON.stringify(props.stops))` in my walk card will returns a call:

```js
props{"poi":
  {"id":"Louvre_Palace",
  "name":"Louvre Palace",
  "coordinates":      
    {"latitude":48.8610214504354,
    "longitude":2.3358494222502717},
    "score":9.80399382095609,
    "images":[
    {"source_id":"wikipedia",
```

But when I try to call it, {props.stops[0].poi.name}, within the Card I get an error that 0 is undefined.  The result is returning an Object, I've tried creating a for loop and mapping over it, but I cannot deconstruct the call to print.

Comment: I think you want `props.poi.name` based on what you logged.

Comment: `props.poi` is returned as undefined -- It is coming in with stops as the key for the object, stops is needed to call the object.

Comment: `props.stops.poi.name`

Comment: I continue to receive the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'poi' of undefined`. As soon as I try to enter the object, it is marked at undefined : `<Col size="md-12"><p>{props.stops.poi.name}</p></Col>`. Even if I try to use a for loop to re-write the information into a new array.

Comment: should work, but many info missing ... exact context/usage ... create working [example] on codesandbox

Comment: Yeah I misread that you were logging `props.stops` instead of `props`, sorry, `props.stops.poi.name`.

Comment: `.then( walk => { setState( { walk } );` instead of `.then(walks => res.json(walks))`

Comment: I cannot set the state, because the call is in my controller on the _server-side_.  My set up is a  _client-side component_ makes a call using a _client-side API_ in my utils folder, which sends to the _server-side controller_ containing all the specific information for the **call (the first code posted)**.  The first two keys are able to be printed by passing them as props up through the client-side.  However, the stops key holds an Object that I cannot unpackage.

Comment: whatever (test api fetching/processing on client [w/o ssr], then pass into backend)... axios (as opposite to fetch) doesn't require json processing ... if it's logged as object (not string) then should be available ... if in loop - other case

Comment: update question, explain your stack and data flow   ... is it a react calling your server witch makes another call to other server using axios? test separately your server (postman) if it returns correct data or inspect network response details, is it properly formatted, contains img etc.

Answer (score 0):

If this is output of `props.stops`, then it's an object and not an array, so `props.stops[0].poi.name` wont work , you can access it as `props.stops.poi.name`

```
{"poi":
  {"id":"Louvre_Palace",
  "name":"Louvre Palace",
  "coordinates":      
    {"latitude":48.8610214504354,
    "longitude":2.3358494222502717},
    "score":9.80399382095609,
    "images":[
    {"source_id":"wikipedia",
```

Comment: It is an object, but using props.stops.poi.name returns unidentified.

Comment: @HeatherGowton, that's why write `If this is output of props.stops`